# Logarithmic scaling of z axis of colormap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with matplotlib: I have a 2D histogram plotted as a heatmap:

[image: 2D-Histogram plotted as heatmap with axis projections]

Now I want to scale the z-Axis of the plot logarithmically. I tried `plt.zscale('log')` but that did not work as the method seems not to exist. Same with `ax.set_zscale('log')`.

Some info on the histogram: I use [hist](https://hist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to make the histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot2D(2DHist, filename):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    2DHist.plot2d_full(
        main_cmap="plasma",
        top_ls="--",
        top_color="orange",
        top_lw=2,
        side_ls=":",
        side_lw=2,
        side_color="steelblue",
        )
    plt.savefig(filename)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you clarify what you mean by z-axis?

Comment: Thanks! Yes of course. Basically the 'height' of the heatmap. The same way I would scale the y-axis of a 1D plot but here in 2D. Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you tried to apply a `log` to the data before creating the histogram?

Comment: In that case, wouldn't you want just scale y-axis because the appearance of the heatmap would be dependent on that?

Comment: That might work, however it would be much more cenvenient for the process of my analysis if I only scaled my data in the last step.

Comment: If I scale the y axis I would stretch the heatmap in that direction along the P_T axis. But that is not what I want :)

Comment: What does `plot2d_full` do?  That is definitely not a Matplotlib method.  In general it is more useful to provide a fully working example.  You may also want to look at colormap normalization, which is what I think you mean by zaxis: https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html